# It is possible to set %property{PropertyName} dynamically?

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm using log4net with C# to logging my app.

I know I can do it like this:

```
GlobalContext.Properties["PropertyName"] = "NewValue";
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

And it works.
But it's not thaaaat dynamic, as I have to call Configure again to set a new value.
Is there a way to set a property value before call ILog.Info?

Something like that:

```
//here I set a new value for %property{PropertyName}
log.Info("Value to log");

//here I set a another one for %property{PropertyName}
log.Info("Value to log 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%property{PropertyName}` in the conversionPattern of your PatternLayout, and you will get a new value logged each time you change the property value.

If you use a property for appender configuration properties, such as a filename or directory for a FileAppender, you will of course need to reconfigure after changing the property value.

Comment: Thanks, but that I've already accomplished that way. I need something more flexible.

Comment: @ramires.cabral - maybe tell us what you need?

Comment: I want to be able to change a property every time I call ILog.Info. I want to give a new name to file based in some events inside my app. With ThreadContext.Properties it's possible, but no without calling Configure. And if I run it in multiple tasks doesnt work properly. You see, I have no experience with log4net. Perhaps this is the wrong approach.

Comment: Are you trying to change the file that a file logging appender writes too using this method? If so, that's not clear from your original question, and this is probably not the best approach. I'd define an appender per file (assuming there's a constrained set) and use filters to filter on a property value. If my assumptions are correct, I'll write a fuller answer for you.

Comment: If you want to be able to change the name of the file to which log4net logs by changing a property, then no, this can't be done with the standard appenders FileAppender and RollingFileAppender.  You would need to write your own custom appender to do this.

Comment: @AndyLamb I don't have constrained set. And I want to create a new file based on some event. I.e. if event a occurs then log to a.log file, else if event b occurs log to b.log file and so on. But if a new event c occurs I want to be able to log that to c.log without knowing before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Log4Net supports various contexts. `GlobalContext`, as you've found, is one of them. `ThreadContext` is another, and I think is more appropriate in your scenario:

```
log4net.ThreadContext["PropertyName"] = "NewValue";
```

There's no need to call `Configure`. Properties set in the `ThreadContext` are available for any calls to the logger from the current thread. Reference the property within the appender config in the normal way:

```
%property{PropertyName}
```

Comment: I think You meant log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["PropertyName"]. Anyway, I've tried your example, but I've had to call XmlConfigurator.Configure(); to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @joe comment I've wrote my own appender as follow:

```
public class MyCustomAppender : RollingFileAppender
{
    bool firstRun  = true;
    string fileNamePattern = null;

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        CloseFile();
        File = fileNamePattern.Replace("__filename__", ThreadContext.Properties["PropertyName"].ToString());
        LockingModel.OpenFile(File, true, Encoding.UTF8);
        LockingModel.AcquireLock();
        OpenFile(File, true);

        base.Append(loggingEvent);
        DoAppend(loggingEvent);
    }

    public override string File
    {
        get
        {
            if (firstRun)
            {
                firstRun = false;
                fileNamePattern = base.File;
            }

            return base.File;
        }

        set
        {
            base.File = value;               
        }
    }
}
```

And it works, which doesn't mean is correct. I don't know if it's a good thing inside the overrode Append method close, acquire lock and open file everytime I log something.
Any thoughts?